# React lifecycle methods as class property arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am now working within an eccentric React codebase where all component functions have been written as class property arrow functions, e.g.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  console.log('componentDidMount');
};
```

There is, of course, no benefit to binding lifecycle methods like this. However, I'm wondering if there are potential downsides, perhaps in the bowels of React to do with inheritance.

Comment: well, they are defined as properties instead, so testing will become a lot harder, I found an article about that once, maybe I can scope it up from somewhere

Comment: You can find the article here: https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Answer (score 1):

I see one downside to class property arrow functions: Imagine some kind of grid where each cell is an instance of the same React component class. If the lifecycle functions were ordinary functions, they would exist only once in memory, on the prototype. If they were class property arrow functions, each cell would have its own copy of the functions. That would impact performance, as measured in the [Medium article](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1) mentioned in the comments. (The claim in that article that a missing prototype complicates testing seems shaky.)

(As an aside, it seems worth mentioning that the whole topic might become obsolete with the adoption of React hooks.)